# How can I remove commit in git log when it has tag

Tags: git

I want to remove the commit and clear up my git log history.

But when I did, some commits was not disappeared.

*(using command : git log --all --graph --oneline)*

I don't know why

Here my example

> [**git log_1**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3b3eP.png)

I made 2 branches(br1, br2), and did not merge it with master.

and then I deleted 2 branches (br1, br2)

But still there are commits in the log('log --all' not 'log')

and also I did reset or rebase to delete them.

> [**git log_2**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UbxNS.png)

Did I something do wrong?

or Can't I remove the commit in log when it has tag?

Comment: A tag is permanent. If you want to remove the history associated with the tag, you have to delete the tag. (The usual caveats about modifying published history apply)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct explanation is that you can't remove a commit *at all*.  It doesn't matter whether the commit has a tag or a branch name associated with it, as far as its *existence* goes.  And it does not matter whether a commit *exists* either!  What matters to `git log` is whether `git log` can *find the commit*.

Obviously `git log` is not going to find a commit that *doesn't* exist.  But sometimes `git log` cannot find a commit that *does* exist.  So the interesting question is really: **When can `git log` find a commit?**

The answer is: **Whenever you give it the right hash ID, either directly or indirectly.**

You give `git log` a commit hash ID directly by typing it in:

```
git log b30a5cf
```

for instance.  Git looks up that hash ID—technically this is a *shortened* hash ID; Git checks to make sure that there is exactly one commit with the full hash ID that starts with this `b30a5cf` number—and having found that commit, `git log` shows that commit.  Then it goes on to show some more commits.

You give `git log` a commit hash ID *indirectly* by doing any of these:

- providing a *name* that translates to a hash ID, such as `master` or `basePoint` for instance;
- providing a flag like `--branches`, `--tags`, or `--all` that tells `git log` to look up *all* branch names, *all* tag names, or *all references*;<sup>1</sup> or
- providing, directly or indirectly, the hash ID of a commit that in turn contains the hash ID of another commit, or perhaps multiple additional commits.

This last point is one of the keys to understanding Git.  *Each commit contains a list of previous commit hash IDs.*  In most commits, this list has just one entry, which Git calls the *parent* of the commit.  So each commit points—backwards, not forwards—to its parent:

```
... <-o <-o <-o ...
```

Here the round `o`s represent commits, with later commits towards the right.  The later commits each point backwards to one earlier commit.

If you run:

```
git log master
```

or:

```
git log b30a5cf
```

you tell `git log` to look up that particular commit, which it does; it shows the commit, and then finds the commit's parent(s), which in this case is just the one commit `c348c14`.  The `git log` command then displays *that* commit, and follows the backwards arrow to the next—or rather, previous—commit and displays that one.

With `--all`, you tell `git log` to start at all commits that have names.  This gets more complicated, because now `git log` has to show multiple commits all at once, and it literally can't.  So it picks out a commit to show based on a *priority*.  Using `--graph` modifies the priority selection so that `git log` can draw the connections from each commit to its predecessor(s).

Deleting a *name* does not delete a commit.  It merely removes your access *to* that commit through that name.  If you have access to that commit through some *other* name, you will still be able to find the commit.  If you memorize the commit's hash ID, then even with no names or other commits providing access, you can access the commit by raw hash ID.

If there are literally *no* names by which Git can ever find a commit, that commit becomes eligible for what Git calls *garbage collection*.  These "abandoned" commits will persist for a minimum of 14 days by default, and 30 days by default for most cases.  After that, `git gc` may decide that the commit has no actual value, and remove it for real.  But you can't remove it directly, and you have no control over precisely when `git gc` will get around to removing it.  All you can do is remove the *names that find a commit* so that you no longer have to see it.<sup>2</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup>A *reference* is the generalized form of "any name that can find some Git object".  Branch and tag names are two kinds of references, but there are many more.

<sup>2</sup>In an emergency—such as after accidentally adding a terabyte database to a Git repository—it's possible to clean these things out manually.  It's rather tricky though.  It's not something you want to do often.

Answer (score 1):

[`git log`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log) will display any commit *reachable*.

Meaning:

- reachable from a branch HEAD
- or from a tag

You would therefore need to delete the tag, not just the branch

```
git tag -d br2-tag
```

Note that all those steps are for your local repository only.
If you had also pushed those branches and tags, you would need to [push their deletion too](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2003515/6309).

```
git push --delete origin br2
git push --delete origin br2-tag
```